# Running a function on post update with new post meta

Tags: theme-development, post-meta, advanced-custom-fields

I am trying to run a function on post update by checking if an ACF is equal to something.

I'm checking if the ACF value is equal to new or closed.

when i change it from value new to closed and save it doesn't run but if i save the post again when the post is at closed it does run.

```
function check_values($post_ID){
    if(get_field('status', $post_ID ) == "closed") {
        sendSMS();
    }
}

add_action( 'post_updated', 'check_values', 10, 3 ); //don't forget the last argument to allow all three arguments of the function
```

Is there something I'm missing about this? I want to avoid saving each post twice.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try using `acf/save_post` action that will hook in after ACF data has been saved.

```
add_action('acf/save_post', 'check_values');

function check_values($post_id){
    if(get_field('status', $post_id ) == "closed") {
        sendSMS();
    }
}
```

Comment: It works! thanks a lot